# Render an IDirect3DSurface9 from DXVA2?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, render, hardware-acceleration, dxva

I got a `IDirect3DSurface9` from `DXVA2` video decoder using hardware acceleration.

I'm try to Render this hardware `IDirect3DSurface9` on My Window via its handle. The following is my summary code.

The first, I call `dxva2_init(AVCodecContext *s, HWND hwnd)`; with `hwnd` is window's handle

```
int dxva2_init(AVCodecContext *s, HWND hwnd)
{
    InputStream *ist = (InputStream *)s->opaque;
    int loglevel = (ist->hwaccel_id == HWACCEL_AUTO) ? AV_LOG_VERBOSE : AV_LOG_ERROR;
    DXVA2Context *ctx;
    int ret;

    if (!ist->hwaccel_ctx) {
        ret = dxva2_alloc(s);
        if (ret < 0)
            return ret;
    }
    ctx = (DXVA2Context *)ist->hwaccel_ctx;
    ctx->deviceHandle = hwnd;
    if (s->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264 &&
        (s->profile & ~FF_PROFILE_H264_CONSTRAINED) > FF_PROFILE_H264_HIGH) {
        av_log(NULL, loglevel, "Unsupported H.264 profile for DXVA2 HWAccel: %d\n", s->profile);
        return AVERROR(EINVAL);
    }

    if (ctx->decoder)
        dxva2_destroy_decoder(s);

    ret = dxva2_create_decoder(s);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, loglevel, "Error creating the DXVA2 decoder\n");
        return ret;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After Decoding successful, I got got a `IDirect3DSurface9`, and I Render it by following function.

```
 int dxva2_render(AVCodecContext *s, AVFrame *frame)
{
    LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 surface = (LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9)frame->data[3];
    InputStream        *ist = (InputStream *)s->opaque;
    DXVA2Context       *ctx = (DXVA2Context *)ist->hwaccel_ctx;

    try
    {
        lockRenderCS.Enter();
        HRESULT hr = ctx->d3d9device->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
        if (hr != D3D_OK)
            return 0;

        hr = ctx->d3d9device->BeginScene();
        if (hr != D3D_OK)
            return 0;

        hr = ctx->d3d9device->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pBackBuffer);
        if (hr != D3D_OK)
            return 0;

        hr = ctx->d3d9device->StretchRect(surface, NULL, pBackBuffer, NULL, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
        if (hr != D3D_OK)
            return 0;

        hr = ctx->d3d9device->EndScene();
        if (hr != D3D_OK)
            return 0;

        hr = ctx->d3d9device->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (hr != D3D_OK)
            return 0;
    }
    finally
    {
        lockRenderCS.Leave();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: All D3D function above: `Clear(), BeginScene(), GetBackBuffer(), StretchRect(), EndScene(), Present()` were return Successful. But the frame was not display on My Window.

I Guess that, I miss some code for integrated My Window Handle with `DXVA2Context`. In this code I only assign: `ctx->deviceHandle = hwnd;` in function `dxva2_init()`.

I search many times, but so far I still cannot find the solution, Anyone can help me?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could help with full code.

Without full code, i suggest you to check your use of StretchRect, just like that :

[IDirect3DDevice9::StretchRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d9helper/nf-d3d9helper-idirect3ddevice9-stretchrect)

> StretchRect Restrictions

- Driver support varies. See the section on driver support (below) to see which drivers support which source and destination formats.
- The source and destination surfaces must be created in the default memory pool.
- If filtering is specified, you must set the appropriate filter caps (see StretchRectFilterCaps in D3DCAPS9).
- etc...

The idea behind this, we don't know nothing about your d3d9device/surface9 (creation/initialization/parameter/etc...), for example.

Also, you can study this code from my project to do dxva2 decoding :

[H264Dxva2Decoder](https://github.com/mofo7777/H264Dxva2Decoder)